# Coffeescript jQCloud handlers

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, visualization

I'm trying to do this in coffeescript,

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6348/8/

Specifically I'm trying to add handlers to my jQWordCloud to get the label for the word being clicked on

In my coffeescript version

```
while i < @counts.length
  x = @counts[i]
  @tag_list.push
    text: x.label
    weight: x.count
    handlers:
      click: ->
        temp = x
        ->
          alert "it worked for " + temp.label
      ()
  ++i
```

I get an unexpected TERMINATOR error presumably because of the (), but if you notice on the jsfiddle, removing that breaks the handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual CoffeeScript approach to this problem is to use [`do`](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

Then just use a plain `for ... in` instead of the `while` loop so that you don't have to muck around with the indexes; something more like this:

```
for o in stuff
  do (o) ->
    tag_list.push
      text: o.NAME
      weight: o.COUNT
      html:
        title: "#{o.COUNT} varieties"
      handlers:
        click: -> console.log("it worked for", o)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3W9YC/

Or you could use a loop comprehension like this:

```
tag_list = for o in stuff
  do (o) ->
    text: o.NAME
    weight: o.COUNT
    html:
      title: "#{o.COUNT} varieties"
    handlers:
      click: -> console.log("it worked for", o)
```

and avoid the `push` calls.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3W9YC/1/

BTW, you can use CoffeeScript at jsfiddle.net by selecting it in the *Languages* panel in the sidebar.

Comment: i had to make some small modifications, but this was a perfect response, thank you!